# Redirecting to another view in spring MVC controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying redirect to another url from one url in spring controller but on its own it changes the url to other than I mentioned and gives 404 error

My spring controller is as follows:

```
 @Controller
@SessionAttributes({ "dataObject", "userId" , "screen" , "scrUpdate" })
public class ScreenDesignerController extends BaseController {
/**
 * Injected screen designer service class.
 */
@Autowired
private ScreenDesignerService screendiService;

@RequestMapping(value = "EditScreen", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String  editScreen(Model model , @RequestBody String tempdata , RedirectAttributes ra) throws Exception {
    ScreenUpdate scrUpdate;
    try {
        logger.info("in editscreen post method: ");
        scrUpdate = screendiService.formatScreen(tempdata);
        logger.info("screenID: " + scrUpdate.getScreenId());
        ra.addFlashAttribute("scrUpdate", scrUpdate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("in editscreen post method: " + e);
    }

    return "redirect:/UpdateScreen";


}

/**
 * Controller get method for Screen Update.
 * @param model Model.
 * @param scrUpdate to create layout for updating screen.
 * @return the template name
 * @throws Exception if anything goes wrong
 */

@RequestMapping(value = "UpdateScreen", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String updateScreen(Model model, @ModelAttribute("scrUpdate") ScreenUpdate scrUpdate) throws Exception {
    try {
        model.addAttribute("screen", scrUpdate);
        logger.info("Update Screen GET");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("inside GET Catch UpdateScreen: " + e);
    }
    return "ScreenDesigner/UpdateScreen";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't give a 404. It gives a 500 Internal Server Error. This usually indicates a bug in the code, like a NullPointerException for example. And the stack trace on the screen or in the logs allows identifying the cause of the error. So, if you want help, post this stack trace, and the relevant code it refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code it seems the GET method to which you are redirecting is expecting (ScreenUpdate)object as Model Attribute please change the get method as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "UpdateScreen", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String updateScreen(Model model) throws Exception {
model.addAttribute("screen", scrUpdate);
return "ScreenDesigner/UpdateScreen";
}
```

and if you want to send ScreenUpdate object to this GET method you can add it in session in post method(editScreen method) and fetch it later in your get method.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I did the way you said. It works fine now. I get the expected object from the POST to GET method and the GET method is shown as successful in the console but the view stays on the "EditScreen" page and doesn't redirect to "ScreenDesigner/UpdateScreen". Please help. Thanks!!

Comment: can you please update your code(please post your latest code).Actually as per rule after redirection your url should change from EditScreen to UpdateScreen

Comment: Hi Abhishek, Above is my updated code. Now it does not throw any error. It receives the object from POST to GET method and the GET method is shown as successful in the console but the view stays on the "EditScreen" page and doesn't redirect to "ScreenDesigner/UpdateScreen".

Comment: Hi code seems to be fine. return the view as follows return "redirect:UpdateScreen"  remove "/" .if still it doesn't redirect check if view is present at particular location or else you can post console log.

Comment: Hi , You can refer this link http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-flash-attribute-example/